# getting name error when try to define urls in Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I want to define URLs in Django but get an error:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
path('', views.index, name="index"),

]
```

the error is:
nameError(name'view' is not defind)

please inform me.

thanks,
Saeed

Comment: Please post the full error (this is not even the error, since it contains a typo) with the traceback, and relevant views, models, urls, templates, ...

Comment: yes, you are right. I get this message. this is not an error.

Comment: you need to import views first to use it in url, consider adding `from . import views` in urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `views`. If you have an app named `myapp` and it has `views.py` inside the app directory, then import it like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views  # <--- Here

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
path('', views.index, name="index"),

]
```

Comment: I should use the word "myapp"? or it should be the name of the application?

Comment: I did import views from myapp but still getting a strange error: AttributeError at /
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Well, thats an error which is inside the index view(i am assuming). But its not the scope of the question. So it would be best if you can ask another question on stack overflow with detailed stacktrace. :)